# Replace Copper Pipe & Gate Valves With PEX Pipe & SharkBite Ball Valves & Fittings

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe, pex, copper

## Summarize the problem

My 35 year-old home's water supply gate valves and outdoor hose bibbs are very difficult to turn on and off.

## Provide details and any research

- The primary water supply comes in from the street to the garage through the bottom of the 3/4" copper pipe (pictured below)
- The 3/4" copper pipe connects to a tee fitting
- The left end of the tee fitting connects to 1/2" copper pipe, a blue gate valve, 1/2" copper, a 90 degree elbow, 1/2" copper pipe through the concrete block wall, ending with a hose bibb
- The top end of the tee fitting connects to a red gate valve (main shutoff) and more 3/4" copper that supplies the rest of the house

## When appropriate, describe what you’ve tried

I created a diagram (pictured below) and plan to:

1. Turn off the water supply at the street and run the main floor faucets to drain the water
2. Cut the copper pipe at all three ends of the tee fitting (pictured below)
3. Cut the 1/2" 90 degree elbow and remove the 1/2" pipe and blue gate valve
4. Cut the 3/4" copper pipe at both ends of the 3/4" red gate valve and remove the gate valve
5. Clean the copper pipe exterior with a [120-Grit Emery Cloth Roll](https://www.homedepot.com/p/202938757)
6. [Ream, deburr, and mark](https://www.sharkbite.com/sites/default/files/2020-05/SharkBite%20Installation%20Instructions%202020.pdf) the 3/4" copper pipe and using the [SharkBite Deburr & Gauge Tool](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/deburr-gauge-tool)
7. Connect a [SharkBite Brass Push Slip Coupling](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/brass-push-slip-coupling) to the top of the 3/4" copper pipe (diagram below)
8. Connect the 3/4" copper pipe to the bottom of the Slip Coupling
9. Connect the 3/4” x 3/4” x 1/2” [Brass Push Reducing Tee](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/brass-push-reducing-tee) to the bottom of the 3/4" copper pipe
10. Connect 3/4" copper pipe to the bottom of the Reducing Tee
11. Connect a 3/4" [Brass Push Ball Valve](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/brass-push-ball-valve) to the bottom of the 3/4" copper pipe
12. Connect the bottom of the Ball Valve to the 3/4" copper pipe
13. Use the 3/4" [Disconnect Tongs](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/disconnect-tongs) to pull the Slip Coupling down to secure the 3/4" copper pipe in place
14. Connect 1/2" PEX pipe to the left end of the Reducing Tee
15. Connect a 1/2" [EvoPEX Ball Valve](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/evopex-ball-valve) to the left end of the 1/2" PEX pipe
16. Connect 1/2" PEX pipe to the left end of the EvoPEX Ball Valve
17. Connect a [EvoPEX 90 Degree Elbow](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/evopex-90deg-elbow) to the left end of the 1/2" PEX pipe
18. Connect 1/2" PEX pipe to the other end of the EvoPEX 90° Elbow
19. Connect a Quarter Turn [Hose Bibb](https://www.sharkbite.com/products/90deg-hose-bibb) to the 1/2" PEX pipe
20. Secure the Hose Bibb to the brick wall with a [Hose Bibb Buddy](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hose-Bib-Buddy-The-HOSE-BIB-BUDDY/5001718713)
21. Ensure the ball valves and hose bibb are off, turn on the water supply at the street, and check for leaks
22. Slowly turn on the 3/4" ball valve and check for leaks
23. Slowly turn on the 1/2" ball valve and check for leaks
24. Slowly turn on the hose bibb, check for leaks, and turn off the hose bibb
25. Check the kitchen and bathroom faucets for leaks

[image: Photo of existing plumbing]

[image: New SharkBite PEX Pipe, Valves, & Fittings]

## Questions

- Is it better to place the main shutoff valve below the tee fitting (shown in the diagram) rather than above the tee fitting (pictured in the photo?
- Am I missing anything?

This will be my first time doing any major plumbing work. Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: I would be replacing the washers in the valves. There is no need to replace valves at that age because they are hard to operate. 
Valve seal replacement is basic homeowner maintenance 101. 
This should be your first step, not replacement unless you just won the lottery and have a lot of $ to waste. There are ways to freeze a pipe and replace a main valve seal but that wasn’t the question.

Comment: Would think main valve should be close to where water comes in before any other fittings.  If that tee(for hose bibb) leaks or need replacement, somebody going to get wet.  You do have a way to turn off water outside of the house?

Comment: @crip659 Yes, I can turn off the water outside of the house by the street. Would moving the main shutoff valve below the tee (pictured in the diagram) solve the problem you stated? Thanks.

Comment: Saves having to go to the street, but those pipes and fittings very seldom give trouble.